# Slack: Get notification when Bot is offline

Tags: slack

I searched the www for a solution to a problem of mine without finding an answer.
I need to get notificated when my bot in slack goes offline, but I don't know how.
To get notificated when he logs in is cacke, because I can set him to send a message, but when he's off there is no option to send a message.
I prefer PHP, Javascript, but other languages are also fine.
Thank you very much for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options how to setup a way to monitor your bot and get notified when it is offline.

One option that has worked well for me is to use an external website to monitor your bot. That website will send requests to your bot every couple of minutes to see if is is still alive and will notify you if the request fails. You may need to extend your bot a bit, so that he can reply to these requests in a proper way.

There are many website that provide this service. The one I use is [uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com/), which also happens to be free for up to 50 monitors.